# How to hide or remove the subgroup labels on a QgsLayoutItemLegend with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer, qgslayoutitemlegend

I'm trying to build a layout with pyqgis and I'm not able to hide or remove the label from the caption subgroup as shown in the image below.

[image]

This is what I have until now:

```
...
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setTitle("Legend")

legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
layerTree = QgsLayerTree()
layerTree.addLayer(t1_t2_total)
legend.model().setRootGroup(layerTree)

style = QgsLegendStyle()  # make new style
style.setFont(QFont("Times New Roman", 8, QFont.Bold)) 

subGroupStyle = QgsLegendStyle()  # make new style
subGroupStyle.setFont(QFont("Times New Roman", 0))
subGroupStyle.setFontColor(QColor("white"))

legend.setStyle(QgsLegendStyle.Title, style)
legend.setStyle(QgsLegendStyle.Subgroup, subGroupStyle) 
legend.setStyle(QgsLegendStyle.SymbolLabel , style)

legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(148, 85, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
legend.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(21, 8, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
layout.addItem(legend)
...
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is [QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendRenderer.html#a22795c95381dd4200ea18f57c58703b9).
The first argument is a [QgsLayerTreeNode](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeNode.html) object and the second is a [QgsLegendStyle.Style](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendStyle.html#acae0c6c735f4cb36f30fc53df74bd84e) Enum object, e.g. `QgsLegendStyle.Hidden`.

Example based on your code:

```py
layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('Layout 1')

t1_t2_total = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('your_layer_name')[0]

legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setTitle("Legend")

legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
layerTree = QgsLayerTree()
# Store a reference QgsLayerTreeLayer object returned by addLayer() method
layerTreeLayer = layerTree.addLayer(t1_t2_total)
# Add this line
QgsLegendRenderer.setNodeLegendStyle(layerTreeLayer, QgsLegendStyle.Hidden)
legend.model().setRootGroup(layerTree)

style = QgsLegendStyle()  # make new style
style.setFont(QFont("Times New Roman", 8, QFont.Bold)) 

subGroupStyle = QgsLegendStyle()  # make new style
subGroupStyle.setFont(QFont("Times New Roman", 0))
subGroupStyle.setFontColor(QColor("white"))

legend.setStyle(QgsLegendStyle.Title, style)
legend.setStyle(QgsLegendStyle.Subgroup, subGroupStyle) 
legend.setStyle(QgsLegendStyle.SymbolLabel , style)

legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(148, 85, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
legend.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(21, 8, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
layout.addItem(legend)
```